# Why can't I use pointer addition instead of malloc

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

I was wondering why I have to use malloc to dynamically create memories,
while I already have pointer addition to freely manipulate the memories.
So I created this code, but this code corrupts, saying that 'stack around the variable 'a' was corrupted'

Can someone explain why this code fails?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a = 1;
    int * arr1 = &a;
    *(arr1 + 1) = 2;
    printf("%d %d\n", *arr1, *(arr1+1));
}
```

Comment: It's undefined behavior.

Comment: While technically *undefined behavior*, the most likely thing is that you are writing into stack memory that isn't yours.  This could manifest itself as another local variable or function parameter gets a changed value.  Or you crash because the return address from the function is messed up - or worse - wind up with the instruction pointer somewhere else when this function returns.

Comment: You need more study of basic concepts. Your title reflects fundamental misunderstanding. Heap allocation with `malloc` reserves storage for use by your program. Pointer arithmetic can be used by your program to read and write values in storage that's already been reserved. Get a good book.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just because you can perform pointer arithmetic on some arbitrary address doesn't mean you should.  C gives you great flexibility to do what you want, but that also means it trusts you to do the right thing, which you are not.

What you are attempting to do is write to a memory address `sizeof(int)` bytes past the address of `a`.  That memory address is not part of `a`, and writing to it invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

As to what is happening in your particular case, local variables are typically stored on the stack in most hosted implementations.  So if you write past the bounds of a variable, you'll most likely be overwriting an adjacent variable or the return address for the function.  Given that your program is crashing, you're probably doing the latter.

Here's an illustration of overwriting another variables:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int before = 0;
    int a = 1;
    int after = 0;
    int * arr1 = &a;
    *(arr1 + 1) = 2;
    printf("%d %d\n", *arr1, *(arr1+1));
    printf("before=%d, after=%d\n", before, after);
}
```

In this example I took your example and added a variable before and after `a`.  When I run this, I get the following output:

```
1 2
before=2, after=0
```

You can see that `before` is now set to 2 even though it wasn't explicitly set.  This means that it appears on the stack right after `a`.  So by writing one past `a`, you end up writing to `before` instead.

To reiterate, this is undefined behavior.  The compiler may arrange variables on the stack in any order.  If you were to for example add an extra `printf` call or compile with different optimization settings you could get different results.  I recompiled the above code with `-O1` and running it resulted in a core dump.

So if need a particular amount of memory and you don't have space explicitly set aside for it, you need to call `malloc` to get the memory you want.  Then you can read and write that block freely.

Answer (score 5):

You have no idea what the implementation might be storing at `&a + 1`. It might be critical information needed to maintain the sanity of the operating environment. Despite having no idea what it might be used for, you modify it. So anything can happen.

Don't write to memory that doesn't belong to you!

Answer (score 0):

You use `int * arr1 = &a;` to request a pointer which points to a. And `arr1` is assigned by system. So the method would be safe to request a pointer.

And for your another case, use `*(arr1 + 1) = 2` to request the pointer `(arr1 + 1)` point to a integer value. You may not know if `(arr1 + 1)` is deployed by other programs or other usage. It's not a safe memory address. So that's the reason the program would be corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

You have assigned address of variable `a` to pointer `arr1`.
arr1 being declared integer pointer arr1+1 increments address by 4(sizeof(int)) ie if arr1 is 0x00000003 arr1 + 1 is 0x00000007

```
*(arr1 + 1) = 2;
```

becomes invalid as its beyond memory allocated for a, writing to invalid memory making your program crash